# Memory leak due to tf.function + custom training function

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks

I got the following model

```
class FRAE(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape, ht, n1, n2, n3, n4, bypass=False, trainable=True,**kwargs):
    super(FRAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.ht = ht
    self.buffer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(1,shape[0] * self.ht), dtype=tf.float32), trainable=False)
    self.bypass = bypass
    self.quantizer = None
    self.trainable = trainable
    
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n1, activation='tanh', input_shape=shape)
    self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n1, activation='tanh')
    self.ls = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='swish')

    self.l3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n3, activation='tanh')
    self.l4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n4, activation='tanh')
    self.l5 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(shape[-1], activation='linear')


def get_config(self):
    config = super(FRAE,self).get_config().copy()
    config.update({'latent_dim':self.latent_dim, 'bypass':self.bypass, 'quantizer':self.quantizer, 
                   "encoder":self.encoder, "buffer":self.buffer,
                   'decoder':self.decoder,"ht":self.ht, "shape":self.shape, "name":self.name})        
    
    return config
      
@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def update_buffer(self, new_element):
    n = self.shape[0]
    self.buffer.assign(tf.keras.backend.concatenate([new_element, self.buffer[:, :-n]], axis=1))

@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def resetBuffer(self):
    self.buffer[:,:].assign(tf.zeros(shape=(1,self.shape[0] * self.ht), dtype=tf.float32))

@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def call(self, x):        
    x = tf.squeeze(x,axis=0)
    decoded = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=tf.shape(x)[0])
    for i in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0]):

        xexpand = tf.expand_dims(x[i],axis=0)
        xin = tf.concat((xexpand, self.buffer), axis=1) # xin = tf.concat((xexpand, self.buffer), axis=1)

        encoded = self.ls(self.l2(self.l1(xin)))
        decin = tf.concat([encoded, self.buffer], axis=1)
        y = self.l5(self.l4(self.l3(decin)))
        decoded = decoded.write(i,y)
        i += 1
        # self.update_buffer(tf.squeeze(y))
        self.update_buffer(y)


    tmp = tf.transpose(decoded.stack(),[1,0,2])
    return tmp

@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def train_step(self, data):
# Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
# on what you pass to `fit()`.
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
        # Compute the loss value
        # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
        loss = self.compute_loss(y=y, y_pred=y_pred)

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    for metric in self.metrics:
        if metric.name == "loss":
            metric.update_state(loss)
        else:
            metric.update_state(y, y_pred)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

which finally runs fine. However, I noticed the memory usage of my program increases every few seconds when I train this model. The cause most likely is the buffer I am using, which is necessary to store intermediate outputs. Currently, I use tf.Variable for this.
More precisely, this line

```
        self.buffer.assign(tf.keras.backend.concatenate([new_element, self.buffer[:, :-n]], axis=1))
```

appears to be the cause. What alternative is there? Calling gc.collect() once in a while did do nothing. I am using tensorflow 2.0, so there is no tf.placeholder. What could I use in my case?

edit:
I just tested, and simple predictions do NOT increase memory consumption. So the leak is occuring during training. My training call is

```
    stoploss = trainutil.stopAtLossValue()
    resetbuffercallback = trainutil.ResetBufferCallback(frae)
    
    
    frae.fit(train_enc_left, train_enc_left, batch_size=1, epochs=10, callbacks=[stoploss, resetbuffercallback], verbose=1)
```

with the callbacks defined as

```
class ResetBufferCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self):
    super(ResetBufferCallback, self).__init__()

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.model.resetBuffer()
   
class stopAtLossValue(Callback):
        def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            THR = 10 #Assign THR with the value at which you want to stop training.
            if logs.get('loss') > THR or math.isnan(logs.get('loss')) is True:
                 self.model.stop_training = True
```

I do not see how the callbacks could result in a memory leak, so likely the custom training_step causes this issue.

edit:
So apparently there is a memory leak in this case if you use @tf.function. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50765
Veeery unfortunate as I need to compile this to get the model to a speed that is ok for training. I cannot compile it without compiling the training step function.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution to this. I had to live without the considerable speed boost and opted for larger batch sizes

Comment: By the way: the leak happens ONLY during training. If you, for some reason, only need inference, then the decorator can be compiled for a considerable speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem the memory leak is causing you? There's not necessarily much you can do to stop the leak itself, except wait for tensorflow to fix the underlying issue, however there are a few mitigation strategies.

If the problem is that you run out of memory during training, then can you either get more memory, or make changes to reduce the memory footprint of your training - enough for training to complete?

If the problem is after training you do not have as much memory as you'd like and you cannot free the memory, then one option would be to run modelling training in a separate process, save the model, then kill the process. At this point the memory will be freed and you can reload the model.

Comment: I cannot finish a single epoch through my training data on my machine. I will have to resort to our cluster for this purpose and restart my training script after every epoch. Having to mitigate by starting separate scripts is very inconvenient and annoying. Apparently there is no other fix. Unfortunately I cannot simply switch to pytorch due to my project partner using Tensorflow. Thank you for your comment!